# Plot multiple lines/functions/whatever with Julia

Tags: plot, julia

I have several functions I would like to plot on the same axis in Julia.  How can I do this?

```
f(x) = x.^2
g(x) = 2*x
t = 1:100
# plot both f and g vs. t?
```

Depending on your backend, you can sometimes just `plot` the first function and then `plot!` the subsequent ones, but this doesn't work so well for the plotly backend (which has to generate a new figure for each plot).  Is there a way to plot both simultaneously?

Comment: Note that you can also build the plot in steps. Start with `p = plot(t, f)`, then `plot!(p, t, g)`, then printing `p` should show the entire plot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call `plot` on a vector of all the things you would like plotted together:

```
plot(t,[f,g])
```

This also works with combinations of e.g. functions and vectors:

```
plot(t,[f,g,t.^2])
```

Comment: thanks, how do I adjust the automatic legend from [y1,y2,y3 ... ] etc?

Answer (score 2):

**For a Jupyter Notebook with Julia v0.6**

I prefer to use pure PlotlyJS instead of going through Plots.jl. Here's a simple example on how to plot two curves on the same axis.

```
using PlotlyJS

X = -5:0.01:5
Y1 = e.^(X)
Y2 = e.^(-X)

trace1 = PlotlyJS.scatter(;x=X, y=Y1, mode="lines", line_color="blue", name="e^x")
trace2 = PlotlyJS.scatter(;x=X, y=Y2, mode="lines", line_color="red", name="e^(-x)")
layout = PlotlyJS.Layout(xaxis_range=[-5, 5], yaxis_range=[0, 10])

PlotlyJS.plot([trace1, trace2], layout)
```

If you wanted to plot two axes side-by-side (each with multiple curves), you can do this

```
p1 = PlotlyJS.plot([trace1, trace2], layout)
p2 = PlotlyJS.plot([trace1, trace2], layout)

# Show the plots next to each other
[p1 p2]
```